# No "size" symbol when debugging in VSCode with gdb

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am trying to debug an application using gdb in VSCode. My launch configuration is the following

```
"launch": {
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
            {
                "name": "CMake GNU GDB",
                "type": "cppdbg",
                "request": "launch",
                "cwd": "${command:cmake.launchTargetDirectory}",
                "envFile": "${command:cmake.launchTargetDirectory}/../generators/conanrun.env", // bin/../../generators/
                "program": "${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}",
                "args": [],
                "MIMode": "gdb",
                "visualizerFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.natvis/STL.natvis",
                "showDisplayString": true
            },
```

The STL.natvis file is from here: https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/main/stl/debugger/STL.natvis

However, when I run my application with the debugger, I get this kind of issues

[image]

What is wrong with this setup? It is really annoying to debug like this...